How to map value objects in dapper
i have the following entity
using MedRaise.Domain.Enums;

namespace MedRaise.Domain.Entities;

public class Appointment : Entity
{
    private Guid _clinicId;
    private DateTime _date;
    private Guid _doctorId;
    private Guid _patientId;

    public Appointment()
    {
    }

    public Appointment(Guid id, DateTime date, Guid patientId, Guid doctorId, Guid clinicId,
        AppointmentStatus appointmentStatus)
    {
        _date = date;
        _patientId = patientId;
        _doctorId = doctorId;
        _clinicId = clinicId;
        AppointmentStatus = appointmentStatus;
    }

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get => _date;
        set
        {
            _date = value;
        }
    }

    public Guid PatientId
    {
        get => _patientId;
        set
        {
            if (value == Guid.Empty) throw new ArgumentException($"The {nameof(PatientId)} is required");

            _patientId = value;
        }
    }

    public Patient? Patient { get; set; }

    public Guid DoctorId
    {
        get => _doctorId;
        set
        {
            if (value == Guid.Empty) throw new ArgumentException($"The {nameof(DoctorId)} is required");

            _doctorId = value;
        }
    }

    public Doctor? Doctor { get; set; }

    public Guid ClinicId
    {
        get => _clinicId;
        set
        {
            if (value == Guid.Empty) throw new ArgumentException($"The {nameof(ClinicId)} is required");

            _clinicId = value;
        }
    }

    public Clinic? Clinic { get; set; }
    public AppointmentStatus AppointmentStatus { get; set; }
}

And 3 value objects
namespace MedRaise.Domain.ValueObjects;
public class Address : ValueObject
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Apartments { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    public Address() {}
    public Address(string country, string city, string street, string apartments, string postalCode)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(country))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Country cannot be empty", nameof(country));
        } 
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(city))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("City cannot be empty", nameof(city));
        } 
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(street))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Street cannot be empty", nameof(street));
        } 
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(apartments))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Apartments cannot be empty", nameof(apartments));
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(postalCode))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Postal code cannot be empty", nameof(postalCode));
        }

        Country = country;
        City = city;
        Street = street;
        Apartments = apartments;
        PostalCode = postalCode;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return Country;
        yield return City;
        yield return Street;
        yield return Apartments;
        yield return PostalCode;
    }
}


namespace MedRaise.Domain.ValueObjects;

public class FullName : ValueObject
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Patronymic { get; set; }

    public FullName() {}
    public FullName(string firstname, string lastname, string patronymic)
    {
        FirstName = firstname;
        LastName = lastname;
        Patronymic = patronymic;
    }
    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return FirstName;
        yield return LastName;
        yield return Patronymic;
    }
}

using MedRaise.Domain.Enums;

namespace MedRaise.Domain.ValueObjects;

public class ContactInformation : ValueObject
{
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public string? Phone { get; set; }

    public ContactInformation() {}
    public ContactInformation(string? email, string? phone)
    {
        Email = email;
        Phone = phone;
    }
    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return Email;
        yield return Phone;
    }
}

I need a select appointment with patients....I have following method but it don't work, i'll get appointment with null fields in patient property and i can't understand, why....Chat GPT didn't help me
    public async Task<Appointment?> GetByIdWithPatientDoctorClinic(Guid id)
    {
        await using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        const string query = """
                                 SELECT 
                                 a.*, 
                                 p.id AS PatientId, p.dob as Dob, 
                             p.address_country AS Country,
                             p.address_city AS City, 
                             p.address_street AS Street,
                             p.address_apartments AS Apartments, 
                             p.sex
                             FROM 
                                 appointments a
                             INNER JOIN 
                                 patients p ON a.patientid = p.id
                             WHERE 
                                 a.id = @Id
                             """;

        var appointments =
            await connection.QueryAsync<Appointment, Patient, Appointment>(
                query,
                (appointment, patient) =>
                {
                    appointment.Patient = patient;
                    return appointment;
                },
                new { Id = id },
                splitOn: "PatientId");

        return appointments.FirstOrDefault();
    }

I tried to do it myself but it didn't work....Can someone help me solve this problem, i'm working with dapper second time

You forgot to include code of the most important type - the Patient. Without it nobody will tell you what's wrong.
Besides that, here are some rules:

If your type have a public parameterless constructor, Dapper will use that constructor and then assign values to properties.
Dapper will use another constructor only if parameterless constructor does not exists, or is inaccessible (for e.g. is private).
When Dapper uses non-parameterless constructor the order and names of arguments have to match order and names of fields in query.
There is one exception: rules 1-3 does not apply if you mark one of constructors with [ExplicitConstructor] attribute. Dapper will use that constructor.
Duplicated names of columns are allowed in top-level query (In your case there is no need to rename p.id as PatientId).
For multi-mappings like .QueryAsync<Appointment, Patient, ...> Dapper uses both column names and columns order to map types.

So to make it work your type Patient have to have a public parameterless constructor and writable properties...
Or your type Patient should have a constructor that accepts following arguments in order: patientId (or id if you remove AS PatientId from query), dob, country, city, street, apartments and sex. This constructor  should be marked with [ExplicitConstructor] attribute.
You are using splitOn parameter correctly. If you remove AS PatientId from query then change it to splitOn: "id".
